# The window i made with qt designer doesn't show up

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, window, qt-designer

I made this window using qt designer i did not add the code that downloads the songs yet but when I run it the window doest show up

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MuziekDownloader(object):
    def setupUi(self, MuziekDownloader):
        MuziekDownloader.setObjectName("MuziekDownloader")
        MuziekDownloader.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MuziekDownloader)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.PageSwitcher = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.PageSwitcher.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 651, 501))
        self.PageSwitcher.setObjectName("PageSwitcher")
        self.Spotify = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Spotify.setObjectName("Spotify")
        self.ConfirmSpotify = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Spotify)
        self.ConfirmSpotify.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 210, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.ConfirmSpotify.setFont(font)
        self.ConfirmSpotify.setObjectName("ConfirmSpotify")
        self.Bynametextlabel_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Spotify)
        self.Bynametextlabel_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 30, 91, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Bynametextlabel_2.setFont(font)
        self.Bynametextlabel_2.setToolTipDuration(0)
        self.Bynametextlabel_2.setObjectName("Bynametextlabel_2")
        self.InputSpotify = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.Spotify)
        self.InputSpotify.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 90, 501, 41))
        self.InputSpotify.setObjectName("InputSpotify")
        self.PageSwitcher.addTab(self.Spotify, "")
        self.Youtube = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Youtube.setObjectName("Youtube")
        self.ConfirmYoutube = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Youtube)
        self.ConfirmYoutube.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 210, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.ConfirmYoutube.setFont(font)
        self.ConfirmYoutube.setObjectName("ConfirmYoutube")
        self.InputYoutube = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.Youtube)
        self.InputYoutube.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 90, 501, 41))
        self.InputYoutube.setObjectName("InputYoutube")
        self.Bynametextlabel_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Youtube)
        self.Bynametextlabel_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 30, 91, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Bynametextlabel_3.setFont(font)
        self.Bynametextlabel_3.setToolTipDuration(0)
        self.Bynametextlabel_3.setObjectName("Bynametextlabel_3")
        self.PageSwitcher.addTab(self.Youtube, "")
        self.Soundcloud = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Soundcloud.setObjectName("Soundcloud")
        self.ConfirmSoundcloud = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Soundcloud)
        self.ConfirmSoundcloud.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 210, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.ConfirmSoundcloud.setFont(font)
        self.ConfirmSoundcloud.setObjectName("ConfirmSoundcloud")
        self.InputSoundcloud = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.Soundcloud)
        self.InputSoundcloud.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 90, 501, 41))
        self.InputSoundcloud.setObjectName("InputSoundcloud")
        self.Bynametextlabel_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Soundcloud)
        self.Bynametextlabel_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 30, 91, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Bynametextlabel_4.setFont(font)
        self.Bynametextlabel_4.setToolTipDuration(0)
        self.Bynametextlabel_4.setObjectName("Bynametextlabel_4")
        self.PageSwitcher.addTab(self.Soundcloud, "")
        MuziekDownloader.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MuziekDownloader)
        self.PageSwitcher.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MuziekDownloader)

    def retranslateUi(self, MuziekDownloader):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MuziekDownloader.setWindowTitle(_translate("MuziekDownloader", "MainWindow"))
        self.ConfirmSpotify.setText(_translate("MuziekDownloader", "Confirm"))
        self.Bynametextlabel_2.setText(_translate("MuziekDownloader", "By URL"))
        self.PageSwitcher.setTabText(self.PageSwitcher.indexOf(self.Spotify), _translate("MuziekDownloader", "Spotify"))
        self.ConfirmYoutube.setText(_translate("MuziekDownloader", "Confirm"))
        self.Bynametextlabel_3.setText(_translate("MuziekDownloader", "By URL"))
        self.PageSwitcher.setTabText(self.PageSwitcher.indexOf(self.Youtube), _translate("MuziekDownloader", "Youtube"))
        self.ConfirmSoundcloud.setText(_translate("MuziekDownloader", "Confirm"))
        self.Bynametextlabel_4.setText(_translate("MuziekDownloader", "By URL"))
        self.PageSwitcher.setTabText(self.PageSwitcher.indexOf(self.Soundcloud), _translate("MuziekDownloader", "Soundcloud"))
```

Coudl someone please help me with this problem cause I already looked at other post and I just couldn't find any solution, or send me links of videos/post where I can find how to fix this. Thanks I advance for any helpers.

Comment: As you can see, generated code contains class definition that is not used anywhere, how can it possibly do anything? To use it you need to create `QApplication` instance, `QMainWindow` instance, `Ui_MuziekDownloader` instance call `setupUi`, `show` and `exec`. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_using_qt_designer.htm

Comment: Note that you should **not** add anything to that file, but instead import it in your actual script as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Answer (score 0):

The file you generated has to be read and executed through another script, with a class that inherits the generated file

try to create a new script and import this file generated by QT and run the script created with this code

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import(QApplication, QMainWindow)
from 'file generated by QT' import Ui_MuziekDownloader
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MuziekDownloader):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    #here the functions of your program will be executed
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

or you can add to the last line of your generated script

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import(QApplication, QMainWindow)
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MuziekDownloader):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
```

[image]